# How to combine two scatter plots in a single plot with arrows showing the direction of time

Tags: plotting, code-request

The following `code` (most critical elements of which from @kglr) works just fine for generating separate scatter plots for two different years (2019 and 2020). My purpose is to combine these time-tagged scatter plots in a single scatter plot in which each country will be represented by a directed arrow from the 2019 observation to the 2020 observation. Since there are too many observations, I like to limit the number of arrows to 10 countries experiencing the largest change. The combined scatterplot should have colored arrows as regional labels (a different colored arrow for each region), and have a separate label showing the directed arrow from 2019 to 2020 to clarify the meaning of the arrows.

```
 fpi19 = {4.91, 5.86, 3.63, 12.16, 3.68, 9.74, 19.67, 8.64, -0.40, 3.34, 1.83, 10.28, 1.67, 
          7.82, 1.75, 1.39, 1.73, 0.20, 9.17, 13.93, 1.63, 8.32, Missing[], 0.14, Missing[], 
          2.78, 2.68, 0.31, 13.73, -3.85, Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], 0.63, Missing[], 
          1.13, 2.33, 4.87, 1.79, 2.42, Missing[], 7.23, 6.54, 2.08};

  fpi20 = {8.79, 5.34, 14.95, 3.87, 0.35, 5.25, 13.30, 7.46, 4.70, 4.73, 5.29, 4.71, 1.42, 1.54,
           4.76, 2.30, 1.38, 2.18, 2.68, -2.53, -1.13, 8.53, Missing[], 6.22, Missing[], 0.61, 
           1.87, 3.97, 2.21, 1.82, Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], 4.68, Missing[], 0.28, 1.61, 
          -8.02, 4.35, 3.75, Missing[], 9.10, 12.72, 2.50};

  pcGDPppp19 = {2542.853, 5330.045, 12131.801, 6991.81, 29073.294, 4142.178, 5203.809, 3622.869, 
          61032.097, 4832.715, 12482.807, 8164.694, 29042.99, 5053.608, 9356.442, 102573.465, 
          19233.878, 3702.838, 10535.168, 16659.476, 43710.261, 12558.483, Missing[], 44573.142, 
          Missing[], 14186.956, Missing[], Missing[], 62266.872, 2220.828, 3891.788, 3467.076,  
          9858.464, Missing[], Missing[], 15915.597, 4022.466, 5818.342, 2590.688, 6137.823, 
          4437.182, 2889.222, 52712.423, 43689.071};

  pcGDPppp20 = {2390.024, 5307.243, 12059.621, 6461.009, 19608.983, 4060.595, 5150.037,
         13214.802, 62371.126, 4695.073, 12221.919, 8110.929, 27402.241, 5241.645, 8452.403, 
         97056.534, 18236.36, 3382.312, 10868.858, 17191.694, 42248.002, 11825.249, Missing[], 
         44620.992, Missing[], 11566.584, Missing[], Missing[], 59519.711, 2199.787, 3786.263,  
         3445.598, 9855.628, Missing[], Missing[], 14308.513, 3833.369, 5652.893, 2454.821, 
         6191.05, 4497.236, 2585.77, 51680.434, 42018.047};

  ClearAll[countries, sAsia, seAsia, eAsia, SIDS, Pacific, groupnames];
  countries = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", 
      "Sri Lanka", "Brunei Darussalam", "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", 
      "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Vietnam", "China", "Japan", 
      "Mongolia", "North Korea", "South Korea", "American Samoa", "Fiji", "French Polynesia", 
      "Guam", "Hong Kong SAR, China", "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands", "Micronesia", "Nauru", 
      "New Caledonia", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", 
      "Solomon Islands", "Tonga", "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu", "Australia", "New Zealand"};

  sAsia = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "India", "Maldives", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka"};
  seAsia = {"Brunei Darussalam", "Cambodia", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", "Philippines", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Vietnam"};
  eAsia = {"China", "Japan", "Mongolia", "North Korea", "South Korea"};
  SIDS = {"American Samoa", "Fiji", "French Polynesia", "Guam", "Hong Kong SAR, China", 
     "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands","Micronesia", "Nauru", "New Caledonia", "Northern Mariana 
     Islands", "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tonga", "Tuvalu", 
     "Vanuatu"};
  Pacific = {"Australia", "New Zealand"};
  groupnames = {"South Asia", "Southeast Asia", "East Asia", "SIDS", "Pacific"};

ClearAll[canonicalnames, groupeddata1, countryToLabeledData1, 
  groupedLabeledData1, groupeddata2, countryToLabeledData2, 
  groupedLabeledData2];

groupeddata1 = DeleteMissing[
   Replace[
    Transpose@{Log[pcGDPppp19], fpi19}, "Missing[]" -> Missing[], All
    ], 1, All
   ];
groupeddata2 = DeleteMissing[
   Replace[
    Transpose@{Log[pcGDPppp20], fpi20}, "Missing[]" -> Missing[], All
    ], 1, All
   ];

canonicalnames = 
  CanonicalName[SemanticInterpretation[#]] & /@ countries;
countryToLabeledData1 = AssociationThread[
   countries,
   Thread[
    Transpose[{Log[pcGDPppp19], 
       fpi19}] -> (Tooltip[
         EntityValue[Entity["Country", #], "UNCode"], #] & /@ 
       canonicalnames)]
   ];
groupedLabeledData1 = 
  DeleteMissing[#, 1, 
     All] & /@ ({sAsia, seAsia, eAsia, SIDS, Pacific} /. 
     countryToLabeledData1);

countryToLabeledData2 = AssociationThread[
   countries,
   Thread[
    Transpose[{Log[pcGDPppp20], 
       fpi20}] -> (Tooltip[
         EntityValue[Entity["Country", #], "UNCode"], #] & /@ 
       canonicalnames)]
   ];
groupedLabeledData2 = 
  DeleteMissing[#, 1, 
     All] & /@ ({sAsia, seAsia, eAsia, SIDS, Pacific} /. 
     countryToLabeledData2);

ClearAll[plot1, plot2];
plot1 = ListPlot[
  groupedLabeledData1,
  Frame -> True,
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  FrameLabel -> {Style["log(GDP per capita PPP), (2019)", 12, Bold], 
    Style["Food price index (2019)", 12, Bold]},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 550,
  PlotLegends -> groupnames
  ]

plot2 = ListPlot[
  groupedLabeledData2,
  Frame -> True,
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  FrameLabel -> {Style["log(GDP per capita PPP), (2020)", 12, Bold], 
    Style["Food price index (2020)", 12, Bold]},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 550,
  PlotLegends -> groupnames
  ]
```

Comment: Am I right that you seek to sort the "distances" that correspond to each country's change and graph the ten largest ones as arrows? Some small countries might produce exaggerated changes that are not representative of larger countries' experience, no? How would you like to filter those?

Comment: @Nicholas G: For a given country A, there are two observations: one for 2019 and another for 2020. I simply wanted to place a directed arrow from the 2019 observation to the 2020 observation. This is independent of other countries' positions on the scatter plot. What happens in other countries have no bearing for country A. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Dear @TugrulTemel, that was clear. The result is that each country covers a distance, from its early coordinates to its coordinates in the second date. You can easily rank those distances according to some metric and take the top few for your graph. The problem I was asking about relates to the idea that some small countries may produce outsize changes. The question is how you will decide whether to drop some or not. If not, then your graph may end up dominated by countries that most people will not find representative. Of course, this might not happen.

Comment: @Nicholas G: Your point is well-received. In fact, there are some small countries showing large changes in percent but small changes in absolute numbers compared to others. Thanks for this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
countryToLabeledData12 = AssociationThread[countries, 
   Thread[Partition[#, 2] & /@ 
        Transpose[{Log[pcGDPppp19], fpi19, Log[pcGDPppp20], fpi20}] ->
      (Tooltip[EntityValue[Entity["Country", #], "UNCode"], #] & /@ canonicalnames)]];

groupedLabeledData12 = DeleteCases[Except[_Rule]] /@ 
  ({sAsia, seAsia, eAsia, SIDS, Pacific} /. 
      DeleteMissing[countryToLabeledData12, 1, All]);

markers = PlotMarkers /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", ListPlot];

legend = LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@groupnames], 
   groupnames, LegendMarkers -> markers, Joined -> False];

options = {PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["log(GDP per capita PPP), (2020)", 12, Bold], 
     Style["Food price index (2020)", 12, Bold]}, 
   DeleteCases[Rule[FrameTicks, _]]@
    FilterRules[Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Business", ListPlot], Options[Graphics]], 
    ImageSize -> 750};

plots = MapThread[ListLinePlot[#, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[#[[All, 2]], Positive[(Subtract @@@ #[[All, 1, All, 2]])] /. 
       {True -> Above, False -> Below}],  
   PlotStyle -> (Function[z, Directive[#2,
     Arrowheads[{{If[ArcLength[Line @ z[[1]]] < 1, .01, .02], 1},
       {0.02, 0, #3}}]]] /@ #)] &, 
     {groupedLabeledData12, ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], markers}] /. 
    l : Line[_?(FreeQ[Offset])] :> Arrow[l];

Legended[Show[plots, options], legend]
```

[image]

**Note:** The function `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme `` is an undocumented internal function. You can see its definition using

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
PrintDefinitions[Charting`ResolvePlotTheme]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I wonder why `Label` names are `Red` in my computer, although yours is `Black`, which I like to have.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, could be version difference. I am using v11.3 (Windows 64b)

Comment: Interesting, I use almost exactly the same version as yours: v11.3 (Windows 64), `b` is missing in mine. Never mind, I will find a solution to that. Thank you again.